# Does bundle adjustment for 2 views make sense?

Tags: computer-vision

is bundle adjustment really usefull if I only have two monocular images? From the idea I have in mind, bundle adjustment would only make sense if I have multiple views/images and thus calculate the reprojection of one (or actually more) 3D point in multiple images. Why? Because I in each image I have e.g. discretization errors which I can mitigate over multiple images with bundle adjustment. If I only consider two views the reprojection error should be nearly zero, isnt it? Or is that wrong and it is also usefull for 2 images, because the essential/fundamental matrix and therefore the relative transformation can be errornous which leads to large errors? I am confused because I've seen some implementation who minimized the reprojection error always only between a set of images.

Answer (score 0):

For the images of a general pinhole camera, it is possible to minimize the reprojection error over two views. The projection of a point and the triangulated 3D location is non-ambiguously defined by two views under central projection. Dependent on the accuracy of your initial estimate / intitial reconstruction result, the effect could be less or more significant.

> From the idea I have in mind, bundle adjustment would only make sense
> if I have multiple views/images and thus calculate the reprojection of
> one (or actually more) 3D point in multiple images.

Well, you need to have some detected image coordinates of a 3D point. Dependent on how many views you have used to triangulate the 3D location of the point, the effect of the bundle adjustment will differ, e.g., a point triangulated from 2 views should be improved, when you have its image coordinates in 3 images and minimize the reprojection error over these 3 views non-linearly instead of performing linear triangulation based on two views.

It also depends on whether you also optimize the camera parameters. In this case, bundle adjustment should be more accurate when its is based on a larger number of images with sufficient view alteration.

In the case of affine imaging properties and camera models, you can only use points that have been detected in at least three images. Otherwise, the results are ambiguous.